# Adware in Chrome

Tags: chrome-for-android, malware

The Chrome browser on my Nexus4 started to showing the same overlay ad on every web site I visit.

I noticed it the first time using a hotel wifi a week ago. The nexus is not rooted but 'installing from unknown sources' is activated.

How can I find out what caused this and and how can I fix it?

**[Update]**

Thanks for the question from Dan Hulme. I also see the ads using a cell connection.

[image: screenshot]
<sup>Screenshot (click image for larger variant)</sup>

p.s. I just noticed the app ad at the top is also always there.

Comment: Have you tried downloading a virus scanner?

Answer (score 0):

It is most likely an app that you installed unknowingly or under false assumptions. To find out which app it is will be the harder part.

First you can look through your list of installed apps, to see if there is anything there you don't recognize.

Next if you installed all your apps yourself (or they came preloaded) start looking at apps which require network permissions (as to serve ads I'm assuming the app would need to have access to the internet), if any of these apps look at all malicious un-install them. Once you have found the offending app you can just reinstall the ones you took of by mistake.

It also may be worth it to uninstall and reinstall the chrome browser just as a precaution.